# Multicollinearity in Gaussian process regression?

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, gaussian-process

Can data multicollinearity be a problem in Gaussian process regression?

Multicollinearity in linear regression essentially makes it hard to determine which features are important in making predictions (but if you are only concerned with making good predictions, you don't necessarily need to fix it) - https://statisticsbyjim.com/regression/multicollinearity-in-regression-analysis

So it seems like predictability won't be an issue. But if we want to determine the degree of importance of each feature in a regression set up - is it even possible to determine this in Gaussian process model, and if so, can multicollinearity be an issue?

Comment: The problem would be perfect multicollinearity that would cause the design matrix to be degenerate. For other cases, the Gauss-Markov assumptions do not cite partial collinearity. However, in order to make an unbiased inference into coefficient standard errors the analysis of residuals must not reveal problems like dependence on the residuals on fitted values, heteroscedastic or not independent residuals.